# I am a newbie please help me configure ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, networking, 64-bit, internet, ubuntu-drivers

I have installed ubuntu but during installation i found it reflected some errors.
Now i am trying to install vlc player and many other software but it shows 
! [snapshot] /home/akash/Desktop/a.part

Answer (score 1):

Your error indicates that you tried to download VLC, and the download was interrupted before it finished. This would be a good way to install VLC in Windows, but it is not the best way to install VLC in Ubuntu. The best way to install VLC in Ubuntu is to open the Ubuntu Software Center, search for VLC, and install it by clicking the **Install** button. This will install the version of VLC from the Ubuntu repositories that is compatible with Ubuntu 12.04.

You should also install the media codecs you need by installing *Ubuntu restricted extras* from the default Ubuntu repositories.